# Laravel8 only works with XAMPP 7.1.33

Tags: mysql, laravel, xampp, laravel-8

so I just installed a fresh Laravel8 Project on my mac.

Before I updated my Mac to BigSur, I was using XAMPP 7.1.33, which worked fine with Laravel. For some unrelated reasons I had to install a new version of XAMPP (7.2.11-0). This worked out fine for Typo3 stuff. But now I discovered that I cannot connect Laravel with Version 7.2, only 7.1 works.

Hostname and Port are in both cases 127.0.0.1 and 3306 - so nothing special.

Typo3 only worked with Version 7.2 - this was due to the PHP Version. Here, when I connected the project to my mysql database, I also used 127.0.0.1 and the 3306 port - and this worked out just fine.

Has anybody discovered a similar problem. I would like to work with XAMPP 7.2, since I do not want to change the local server all the time.

Comment: Have you considered using Valet instead? It's made for Mac and setting it up is a breeze

Comment: I already have Valet installed and even the MySQL Connection works as well, as far as I can tell. But I want to access my MySQL database via phpmyadmin and that wont work...